# BugBear: Unanswered isn't

Tags: support, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

The Unanswered section contains buckets of answered questions.

Especially if you start at the end (hunting for interesting ones).

Further, i've found one question which it appears had answered, but which were merged with another, duplicate/similiar question.

My bug bear = all of this stuff is stuff I would not expect to see in the Unanswered section.

Unanswered might as well not be there!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

> **Answered** questions have at least one answer with one upvote (or accepted)
> **Unanswered** questions have no answers with upvotes (or accepted)